# How does C# compiler search for libraries during compilation?

Tags: c#, msbuild, csc, search-path

A C# program uses .Net framework libraries or third party libraries by `using` directive in the C# code.

When compiling the program using `csc`,

- how shall we specify the search path for the used libraries?
- does the compiler search for the used libraries in some search order?

I am comparing `csc` to `gcc` and `javac` in terms of specifying search paths for libraries and searching order.  For `gcc` and `javac`, there are multiple ways to specify search paths,

- command line options to them, such as `-L` to `gcc` and `-classpath` to `javac`;
- environment variables, such as `LIBRARY_PATH` for `gcc` and `CLASSPATH` for `javac`;
- default paths, such as current directory, some system-wide directory

Does `csc` also have multiple ways, and have a search order between them?

Same questions if compiling the program using `msbuild` which calls `csc`.

Thanks.

Comment: _"...by using directive...."_ - well no it doesn't.  It uses _references_ via `/reference xxxx`.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/reference-compiler-option

Comment: Does the C# program need to use `using` in the C# code to use libraries?

Comment: Do many people actually directly use csc?  I know it can be done but generally every .NET shop I've ever worked in used MSBuild.  The .CSPROJ file would tell MSBuild which would tell CSC where to look for references.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter Thanks. I asked for learning purpose. Where can I find more about "The .CSPROJ file would tell MSBuild which would tell CSC where to look for references"?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/wiki/ResolveAssemblyReference

Answer (score 0):

> how shall we specify the search path for the used libraries?

Use the `/lib` command line option.

Syntax

```
/lib:dir1[,dir2]
```

> **dir1**
>
> A directory for the compiler to look in if a referenced assembly is not found in the current working directory (the directory from which you are invoking the compiler) or in the common language runtime's system directory.
>
> **dir2**
>
> One or more additional directories to search in for assembly references. Separate additional directory names with a comma, and without white space between them.

OP

> Same questions if compiling the program using msbuild which calls csc

If you use msbuild you are more than likely using a **.proj** file so it would use the path setup for your environment I would expect

### Tell me more

- [-lib](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/lib-compiler-option)

Comment: Thanks. (1) For gcc and javac, there are multiple ways to specify search paths:     command line options to them,     environment variables, and    default paths. 
Does `csc` also have multiple ways, and have a search order between them? (2) How about the questions in my post when using `msbuild`?

Comment: Thanks. Does `csc` use other ways such as environment variables or default values for search paths, besides command line option `/lib`?